# Ruby On Rails Model/Controller Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a CourseCategory model and a Course Model along with corresponding controllers course_categories and courses. A course belongs to a category and a category has many courses.

I want to have a page that shows courses in a particular category. Which controller does this function belong in? Should I nest these resources? Just looking for the best way to model this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CourseCategories. Think of your URLs, thats the easiest way to make a decision like this:

`example.com/course_categories/1`

--or, better, use slugs for categories instead of ids and you'd get--

`example.com/course_categories/awesome_courses/`

However, it might be worthwhile to consider simple having a "categories" model rather than a "course_categories" model. Then you could nest categories under courses, and you'd get something like:

`example.com/courses/categories/1` or `example.com/courses/categories/hard`

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are going to be displaying a coursecategory listing - therefore would belong in the coursecategory controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this so the courses controller and take a parameter saying which category to respond with.

Or, if it makes sense, you can make courses a nested attributed of course_categories.  Then this will be the default behavior.

*EDIT* Since I gave the opposite answer of someone else.  The first suggestion would let you

```
/courses?course_category=math
```

or

```
/courses/math
```

Then look for the course_category in the controller

The second idea would let you do

```
/math/courses
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to do something like

routes.rb

```
resources :course_catgeories do
   resources :courses
end
```

courses_controller.rb

```
def index
   @course_category = CourseCategory.find(params[:course_category_id])
   @courses = @course_category.courses
end
```

The logic here being, if you're listing courses for a category, then the conventional action for that is the index action.  Except in this case, you're scoping the listing to a particular category.  So if you think about it in those terms, I think this approach better models your domain.

This approach effectively produces the following routes:

/course_categories/ (category index page)
/course_categories/1 (category show page)
/course_categories/1/courses (course index page)
/course_categories/1/courses/1 (course show page)